# Run node.js on a web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webserver

I am trying to run a nodejs application when a webpage loads, however it is not working. I have tried to use express to create a server from within node but whenever I try to load the webpage I get an error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Here's the code I'm using to connect to my server:

```js
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log('web page opened');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

In the console, I see "Listening on port 3000" but I cannot connect to the website (http://45.55.71.134:3000/test).

Does anyone know any solutions to this? Thank you.

Comment: What/where is this server? Can it accept incoming connections over port 3000? What if you try loading the page from the server itself? Many variables here...

Comment: Your `app.get` needs to actually send a response back. Right now it's just going to accept the connection and do nothing. try `res.send('howdy');`

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager Hmm, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code you posted *is* your server right? This sentence in your question is kinda misleading: "Here's the code I'm using to connect to my server:"

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager Yes

Answer (score 0):

the get statement indicates you are listening at port 3000 for '/test' but the url you used has '/some'.  Try changing to '/test'?

Comment: Oh sorry for the late reply. That still doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are listening on url `/test`, but you are requesting on
   `/some`. Change that.
2. If you are running the server locally, first
       try to connect with `localhost:3000`.  If that succeeds, then it is a
           problem in your router or firewall settings and you might need to
           open that port.

Comment: I changed it and it didn't do anything. Also, this is on my host, I'm not running it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is timing out because you are not closing the request. The browser is still waiting to recieve some data from the server, but you only have `console.log("web page opened")`, which is on the server and not browser. The browser gives up after a while waiting for the server response and that is why you get that error.

```
//Do this
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    //instead of this
    console.log('web page opened'); //This doesn't do anything.
    //Try this instead
    res.send("web page opened"); 
});
```

You need to always close a request. You could also have called the `next()` function like this to force close -

```
 app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
     console.log("web somehting");
     next();
 }
```

Comment: I tried both of those and neither changed what happens. Do you have Discord or something that could be more useful to chat on rather than here?

Comment: Hmm, I got it working, but there's one more issue. It works with cURL, but not when trying to connect to the page from chrome.

Comment: Go here http://localhost:3000/test  make sure your server is running on your machine.